# MVC6 putting the script in the custom taghelper in a @section Scripts{ } container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

I have a custom taghelper with a string builder based in part on [this](http://our.componentone.com/2016/02/01/taghelpers-how-to-create-taghelper-for-jquery-ui-autocomplete/) website for autocomplete. It works however like the ComponentOne example I had to move the jquery and jquery-ui scripts from the bottom of the _Layout page to the top.

I would like a situation where my script is placed at the bottom while my input text box is where I placed the taghelper.  I can use the:

```
@section Scripts { }
```

container around the actual taghelper but of course that sends the textbox to the bottom of the page along with the script.

Is there a way in the custom taghelper to place "@section Scripts {}" in the output just for the jquery script leaving the textbox to render where the taghelper was placed?

Comment: Anybody got any ideas on this.. would like a way of forcing the script, built in string builder, to be placed at the bottom of the page while not affecting the input textbox's position. There must be a way of enclosing it with "section scripts" etc or is there another way..

Comment: I am thinking that the MVC team have not included this functionality - tell me if I am wrong... Its specifically not included in View components but they are still determining if they might add it. Thing is I would like a taghelper to be a piece of code that has both the markup and the scripts as per the ComponentOne example... good idea but unless you force jquery and jquery-ui to load first its a waste of time. By having a @section option you can force you jquery code down to the bottom of the page thus not disturbing the _Layout file and avoiding possible renderbocking..